# Ionic1 app gets reload on clicking a button

Tags: ionic-framework, reload

I have an ionic app with side-menu. My requirement is to have a Login Page before side-menu page.
By clicking on login button first time application gets reload, on clicking second time navigates to the side Menu page.
Here is my code

**app.ts**

```
config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  })

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    cache: true,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: "homeController"
      }
    }
  })

<ion-view>
<ion-content>
<div class="login-main-heading">

  <h3 class="all-elements-center login-heading">Welcome</h3>

<div class="form-elements responsive-sm">
  <h5 class="all-elements-center login-heading">Login</h5>
  <form action="">
    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
             <i class="icon ion-person placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="User Name">
          </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
             <i class="icon ion-lock-combination placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </label>
      <div class="responsive-sm">
        <button class="button button-large button-assertive button-login">
           Login
        </button>
        <button class="button button-large button-assertive button-signup">
            Sign Up
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive button-facebook-    login" ng-click="login()">
           Login 
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**login-controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
$scope.login = function () {
$state.go('app.home');
}
});
```

**app-controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state) { 
});
```

Comment: And what do you want? what is the question?

Comment: Why application get reload on clicking a button on first time?
2nd time clicking on the same button navigate to side-menu.
Not navigating to side-menu on first click but 2nd click work fine.
hope you get my problem

Comment: You can save the userId in your localstorage and check it at start of your app. If that id exist redirect to any page you want and if it dont exist then redirect to login page.